# JS new Date() jump to next year

Tags: javascript, html

For a few days, I have had a problem with the date processed by JS, which would try to make the year jumps forward. A bit of sample code below.

Inicjal date in HTML 'Jan 19 2022'

```
  var dateYear = $(this).attr("dateYear");
  console.log('dateYear ' + dateYear); // dateYear 2022

  var dateMonth = $(this).attr("dateMonth");
  console.log('dateMonth ' + dateMonth); // dateMonth 12
  var dateDay = $(this).attr("dateDay");
  console.log('dateDay ' + dateDay); // dateDay 19
    
  var myDate = new Date(dateYear, dateMonth, dateDay);
  console.log('myDate ' + myDate); // myDate Thu Jan 19 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
```

Even if it subtracts one index from a month, but the year jump to 2023, if the index of the month remains unchanged teddy data will be 'Feb 19 2022';

What could it be for two years there was no problem with the date.

Comment: Months start at 0, not 1. So you're telling JavaScript to create a date in the month **after** Dec 19 2022 -- which is Jan 19 2023.

Comment: Month is indexed base (0-11) so `12` is January of the following year

Answer (score 2):

This is JavaScript.

January is `0`.

December is `11`.

See [Date.prototype.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth).

Comment: Thank you for the hint tao
I'm about to code something and throw it here.

Comment: Should add that I gets the date from php, but one if solved the problem.